# Centering plots with baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, baseline

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \captionsetup{skip = 5pt}
        \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=12cm,
            height=9cm,
            xmin=10^0,xmax=10^6,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.08,
            xlabel = {$R_4$ ($\SI{}{\ohm}$)}, ylabel={$P_{R_4}, P_{R_5}$ ($\SI{}{\watt}$)},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            samples=1000, 
            grid=both, 
            legend pos = outer north east] % by default 
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = 1:10^6] {(78/(9*x + 2750))^2*x};
                \addlegendentry{$P_{R_4}$};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = 1:10^6] {144*(x + 125)^2/(25*(9*x + 2750)^2)};
                \addlegendentry{$P_{R_5}$};
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This plot.}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \captionsetup{skip = 5pt}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {r1 = 0.8; 
                                                A1 = 4*r1;
                                                B1 = 1000*r1 - 4225;
                                                C1 = 62500*r1;
                                                r2 = 1.2;
                                                A2 = 4*r2;
                                                B2 = 1000*r2 - 4225;
                                                C2 = 62500*r2;
                                                R41 = (-B1 - sqrt(B1^2 - 4*A1*C1))/(2*A1);
                                                R42 = (-B2 - sqrt(B2^2 - 4*A2*C2))/(2*A2);
                                                R43 = (-B2 + sqrt(B2^2 - 4*A2*C2))/(2*A2);
                                                R44 = (-B1 + sqrt(B1^2 - 4*A1*C1))/(2*A1);}]
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=12cm,
            height=9cm,
            xmin=10^0,xmax=10^6,
            ymin=0,ymax=2.5,
            xlabel = {$R_4$ ($\SI{}{\ohm}$)}, ylabel={$P_{R_4}/P_{R_5}$},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            samples=1000,
            grid=both]
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = 1:R41+1] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = R41:R42+1] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = R42:R43+10] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = R43:R44+10] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = R44:10^6] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{That plot.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a way to center the top plot such that its center of x-axis aligns with that of the bottom plot (or more generally, the vertical line in the center of the paper)? I know that `\baseline` can do, but I am not sure what to put for the parameters.

Comment: The probem is due to the `\centering` and the fact that the top plot has a lengend and the bottom does not. Simple fix would be to move the legend to be on the plot. Or, also include the legend with the bottom plot in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the keys `trim axis left, trim axis right` are for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \captionsetup{skip = 5pt}
        \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=12cm,
            height=9cm,
            xmin=10^0,xmax=10^6,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.08,
            xlabel = {$R_4$ ($\SI{}{\ohm}$)}, ylabel={$P_{R_4}, P_{R_5}$ ($\SI{}{\watt}$)},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            samples=1000, 
            grid=both, 
            legend pos = outer north east]
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = 1:10^6] {(78/(9*x + 2750))^2*x};
                \addlegendentry{$P_{R_4}$};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = 1:10^6] {144*(x + 125)^2/(25*(9*x + 2750)^2)};
                \addlegendentry{$P_{R_5}$};
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This plot.}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \captionsetup{skip = 5pt}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right,
                            declare function = {r1 = 0.8; 
                                                A1 = 4*r1;
                                                B1 = 1000*r1 - 4225;
                                                C1 = 62500*r1;
                                                r2 = 1.2;
                                                A2 = 4*r2;
                                                B2 = 1000*r2 - 4225;
                                                C2 = 62500*r2;
                                                R41 = (-B1 - sqrt(B1^2 - 4*A1*C1))/(2*A1);
                                                R42 = (-B2 - sqrt(B2^2 - 4*A2*C2))/(2*A2);
                                                R43 = (-B2 + sqrt(B2^2 - 4*A2*C2))/(2*A2);
                                                R44 = (-B1 + sqrt(B1^2 - 4*A1*C1))/(2*A1);}]
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=12cm,
            height=9cm,
            xmin=10^0,xmax=10^6,
            ymin=0,ymax=2.5,
            xlabel = {$R_4$ ($\SI{}{\ohm}$)}, ylabel={$P_{R_4}/P_{R_5}$},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            samples=1000,
            grid=both]
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = 1:R41+1] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = R41:R42+1] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = R42:R43+10] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = R43:R44+10] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = R44:10^6] {4225*x/(4*(x + 125)^2)};
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{That plot.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that! Thank you so much!